# How can I add an intranet-only endpoint to my IIS hosted WCF service?

Tags: wcf, iis, configuration-files

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS that uses basicHttpBindings. I'm adding a new method to the ServiceContract that will be called from a console app to perform an administrative task. I got to thinking, well wouldn't it be nice if I gave this method its own endpoint. Then I thought and what if that endpoint wasn't even publicly accessible. It would be much better if only a computer on our LAN could access it. It might even be cool if only an AD administrator was authorized to use it, but I don't want to get too elaborate. So I added a new ServiceContract interface that includes my new method. How can I restrict it to LAN access only? Do I need a NetTcpBinding? Networking is not my strong suit and I'm a little confused, conceptually, on how a TCP endpoint could be hosted from IIS. Additionally, when hosting multiple endpoints, does each have to have its own address or can they be at the same address?

Comment: I've found these pages, but is this what I need?
http://dotnetmentors.com/hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-or-netnamedpipebinding-in-iis.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am gonna answer some of your questions

- there is no binding that would limit access to LAN network though you can use windows authentication to allow users from your network to use the service
- the nettcpbinding is only a tcp connection and you can host it on IIS pof course
  check this link for more information [hosting nettcp on IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/santhoshonline/archive/2010/07/01/howto-nettcpbinding-on-iis-and-things-to-remember.aspx)
- you can have one base address for multiple endpoints , example:
  https://localhost:8080/calculator.svc

  net.tccp://localhost:8080/calculator.svc

Comment: So I can't configure the TCP base address on a port that has incoming requests blocked by the firewall?

Comment: That you can do ,,, try hosting your WCF service on a console app with the desired nettcp endpoing  , test your service before deploying to IIS